# Problem installing an app on a device - NO PERMISSIONS

Tags: android, permissions, device

I'm trying to install my test app on my device, but I does not go there.

I've also prepared my phones as described here:  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

1 - In eclipse I see the device with '??????????' as ID.

2 - with adb device, I get:

```
 List of devices attached
```

????????????    no permissions

I edited the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules....not sure what else to do?

3 - I copies the app to my SD card and tried to installed it from there ... but at a point the installation stopped and the message was 'Application not installed'

Also! The app gets intalled on my friends phone via eclipse?

Can anybody give me a hand with this???

Thanks!

Comment: Telling us what's your device, what Android version it's running, and whether it's rooted/modified might help us

Comment: it's Dell Streak, Android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely beyond my comprehension - the device got found (recognized) after deselecting the Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging....

:) I signed with relief ...

Thank you very much for the enthusiasm and help!

Comment: Glad you got it rolling, forgot to mention to check that ;).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your machine is connected to the Phone device correctly..

If the error persists, you can try restarting the adb server, using following commands:
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices

If the error still persists, try restarting both your development machine and phone device.

Comment: If this doesn't work, start the server as root. `sudo ./adb start-server`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that before when the user you are running as did not have permissions. If you're using Ubuntu try running adb via sudo:

> sudo adb devices

If you're using another distro either try as root, or use sudo, accordingly. (Assuming you're using Linux, and probably Ubuntu, if you're in that part of the instructions on the page you linked -- but that info in the question would help too.)

Also make sure you're using the correct vendor ID for the device you're trying to use. The instructions show 0bb4 as an *example* only (that will only work for certain HTC devices). You can use the *lsusb* command to check to make sure you're device is detected by the OS, and get the correct ID.

```
lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 100: ID 18d1:4e12 Google Inc. Nexus One Phone (Debug)
```

Comment: Could it be something from the device itself? Although I did all the setting described?